# Facebook Messenger Persistent Menu Send Payload from web_url

Tags: menu, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I would like to send a `type:postback` with `payload:My Message` through an HTML page defined in a web_url. I have these codes:

```
    {
      "title": "Open Hello World Popup",
      "type": "web_url",
      "url": "https://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx/testpage.html",
      "webview_height_ratio": "tall",
      "webview_share_button": "hide",
      "messenger_extensions": true
    },
    {
      "title": "Send Hello World!",
      "type": "postback",
      "payload": "SEND_HELLO_WORLD"
    },
```

How do I send a postback with a message payload from a link or button defined in my testpage.html

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<a href="POSTBACK_SEND_HELLO_WORLD???">Send Hello World!</a>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**m.me links**
If the user hasn't already started a chat with you page on facebook, then you should be able to use a m.me link.

For Example:
I want to send a custom payload "HELLO_USER" that will trigger after the "Get Started" Button is clicked.

m.me link that will be used on html page:

```
http://m.me/<YOUR_PAGE_NAME?ref=HELLO_USER
```

In your webhook you should receive an event after the "Get Started" button is clicked with the data ref that is passed. Retrieve the ref from the referral object in your webhook event.

Check out the docs 
[Facebook m.me links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links)

Also, check out the Send to Messenger Plugin if you want the webhook event to trigger without pressing the "Get Started" Button.

[Send To Messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin)

Hope this helps.